# Since IntelliJ 2016.3, classes doesn't get recompiled on restart

Tags: java, intellij-idea

since I've updated to IntelliJ 2016.3 on my mac, it seems like classes doesn't get recompiled if I restart my application. I always need to call mvn compile which I didn't need to do before the update. I didn't found anything that would explain such a behaviour. Am I missing something?

Edit:
With restart I mean rerun my app in debug mode. See the screenshot. (Needed to black out a few things due to security reasons)

[image]

Comment: If by restart you mean clicking the green play button. Go to Run->Edit configurations, then paste a screen shot of what's in there in the question.

Comment: I have 2016.2, and it says Make not Build. You could try adding a new run configuration. What version of IntelliJ did you have before?

Comment: I had 2016.2. I have no step called "make". There's only Build and Build Porject. (And a bunch of other unrelated stuff)

Comment: Well it looks ok. Personally, I would start a new project and see if that behaves as expected. If it doesn't then you have a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for the question. If it does behave, you have something to compare to.

Comment: Same is occurring for me in 2016.3. Java class files will get "stuck", and then I have to go delete them manually--and sometimes this doesn't even work! at which point I have to restart intellij. WTF